# vertically align text within itself

Tags: html, css

I have an `h3` with a height of `100%`. Therefore the height is unknown. How can I center the text within itself? For the sake of the example, I have given the parent fixed dimensions but this is not the case. I have tried using vertical align but that doesn't work, I believe I may need to change the `display` to do that?

I don't want to center the text within its parent, I know various methods to do this. I want to know if it is possible to vertically center it within itself. The text needs to be 100% in both dimensions so that the link fills the parent div.

```css
.unknowndimensions{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  }
.unknowndimensions h3{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:#f7f700;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="unknowndimensions">
  <a href="#"><h3>Title</h3></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @HaydenSchiff This is a great resource, I use it often but the methods it uses won't work on this example.

Comment: @misterManSam No this is not the same problem. This is not text within a div. The solution will be totally different.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is in a div or not. That is how you vertically center text with CSS

Comment: @Gorg - This question has been asked countless, probably hundreds, of times. Look through the existing answers and pay particular attention to `display: table` or `display: flex` solutions.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, That is how you center a text element within a div. What I want to know is how to center text within its self.

Comment: @misterManSam Please provide an example, I can't find one.

Comment: You need a container of some sort, and you have one, the h3 element.

Comment: Its the same thing. Those methods can apply to any DOM element. Not just a `div`.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Nope, it's definitely different.

Comment: @gorg nope, it's entirely the same

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/4639281) (from the linked canonical question) uses the exact same method as the answer which you have accepted here, and does so with a better and more complete explanation.

Comment: @TinyGiant I haven't accepted an answer. As all of the answers provided only show how to center text within a parent element. which isn't my question.

Comment: @Gorg - Doesn't [this example I made meet your criteria](https://jsfiddle.net/9xL48r7o/)? It's the same thing as the others... the h3 is 100% high and wide

Comment: @misterManSam Awesome, yes it does! I was using the flex examples on the parent div. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using table method,

```css
.unknowndimensions{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  }
.unknowndimensions a{ 
  display:table;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
  }
.unknowndimensions h3{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:#f7f700;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="unknowndimensions">
  <a href="#"><h3>Title</h3></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool answer, I had been using a hacky empty <span> to make the link fill the container. I was sure there had to be another way. This answer fits the bill.